# Is there any protocol supported by codename one to discover devices in local network and pair them? Like UPnP, mDns?

Tags: java, sockets, codenameone

I'm looking for some protocol for pairing device based on esp8266 with mobile app. I know i can write Android app using JAVA, build an RARP table, read the IP comparing physical address of the esp8266 and connect to it directly using TCP, since i can put esp8266 into server mode, but i cannot find a way to build RARP table in codename one because java.net.* are not supported. I was looking for other protocols, but found nothing supported yet. Do you have any suggestions? Let me admit that esp8266 IP has to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

We have `Socket` but it doesn't support broadcast. For that you will need to use native interfaces and can use `java.net` on Android. On iOS you will need to use the native iOS API's to do that.

See this tutorial on using native interfaces: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html